# How to make a section id menu w/multiple pages

Tags: menus

I have pages with multiple sections like

```
/about#section_one
/about#section_two
```

Thats how I add them in Menus under Custom Links
but Wordpress changes to

```
 /about/#section_one
```

(adding a slash before the pound symbol)
How do I fix this?

Comment: You don't have to. The anchor still works.

Comment: By default WordPress adds a trailing slash on everything if you're using pretty permalinks. If your URL does actually end in /about with no slash, it could be your .htaccess settings.